# Regarding Ubuntu installation on end user machines

Tags: installation, commercial

If someone is working in computer maintenance industry and working on customer call bases then can he install Ubuntu on end use machine?

As most of the end users are using pirated Windows software, can we provide them with a legal copy of Ubuntu at no cost, and charge end user for technical support.

Please consider legal issues also when answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has always been and always will be free. That's the sort of philosophy that most of the linux based distros have, and is one that Ubuntu has pioneered. If you wish to install Ubuntu on a large number of machines there is no need to purchase a bulk license  something that would be needed with an operating system like Windows. There is definitely no legal issues with installing Ubuntu, the .iso files are there on [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page for free downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu follows the policy of free to everyone. It is an open source operating system that comes absolutely free of cost you can install it in as many systems as you like. It comes under GPL i.e. General Public Licaense which states it's purpose. You can get most of the softwares as well using the Ubuntu's official repository that too absolutely free of charge without wandering here or there.

**That's the power of open-source use it, distribute it modify it whatever you like either for your personal use or for commercial use its FREE!!!**